# Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm new to R and I use the following code and get the error message:

Error:

> Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.

```
binning<-woe.binning(df_train, target.var="Target",pred.var=colnames(df_train) 
[colnames(df_train)!='Target'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this colnames(df_train)!='Target'  , you will get true and false as an output.

Comment: You can try using `setdiff(colnames(df_train),'Target')` instead of `colnames(df_train) 
[colnames(df_train)!='Target']`

Comment: I tries both. Still getting the same error

Comment: try coercing to a Vector using `as.vector()` and see what happens. Also `print(colnames(df_train)!='Target')` so you can see what is happening.